# How to detect char sequences where each successive char differs from the previous one by minimal alphabetical difference (1)?

Tags: javascript

I want to detect sequences of characters where each successive char differs from the previous one by 1, where 1 is its "alphabetical difference". In the standard alphabet, `index("b")-index("a")=1, index("z")-index("y")=1, index("z")-index("x")=2`, and so on. 
What I want is to replace such sequences with its first and last chars, removing everything that is between. Note that if there are only two chars in such sequence, there is no need to replace. And there is no need to replace if the order is reverse, e.g. `"dcba"`.
For example,

```
"dabcehklopqrsafxwvu012345678910210"
```

should be transformed into

```
"dacehklosafxwvu0910210"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, yesterday I solved exactly the same problem :).

Take a try with the following solution:

```
var str = "dabcehklopqrsafxwvu012345678910210";

var res = Array.prototype.reduce.call(str, function(acc, item, index, strAr) {
  var pushItem = 
      //first item always included
      index === 0 || 
      // last item always included
      index === strAr.length - 1 || 
      // include the first item in sequence
      strAr[index - 1].charCodeAt(0) + 1 !== item.charCodeAt(0) ||
      // include the last item in sequence
      strAr[index + 1].charCodeAt(0) - 1 !== item.charCodeAt(0)
  if (pushItem) {
    acc += item;
  }
  return acc;
}, '');

console.log(res); // prints "dacehklosafxwvu0910210"
```

Check the [working demo](http://jsbin.com/jujijat/2/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 1):

A single loop solution

```js
var code = 'dabcehklopqrsafxwvu012345678910210',
    result = '',
    i = 0, l;

for (i = 0, l = code.length; i < l; i++) {
    result += 
        i > 0 &&
        i + 1 < l && 
        code.charCodeAt(i - 1) + 1 === code.charCodeAt(i) &&
        code.charCodeAt(i) + 1 === code.charCodeAt(i + 1) ?
            '' : 
            code[i];
}

document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the sample answer that you typed is not correct... as you still have kl after each other...

anyways, your code should looks like something like below:

```
var x = "dabcehklopqrsafxwvu012345678910210";
    var z = x;
    for (var i = 1; i < x.length - 1; i++)
        if (x.charCodeAt(i) == x.charCodeAt(i + 1) - 1) {
            x = x.replace(x.charAt(i) + x.charAt(i + 1), x.charAt(i));
        }
    alert(x);
```

The question here is if 12345 should it be 135, in your sample klopq became klo ...?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work well. It returns `dacehkoqsafxwvu0246810210`, but it should be `dacehklosafxwvu0910210`.

Comment: How do you explain "kl" in your answer "dacehklosafxwvu0910210" ??

Comment: `da(b)cehk(-empty-)lo(pqr)safxwvu0(12345678)910210`. `kl` is present because `mn` is missing.

Comment: There is **nothing** between `k` and `l`, so there is no need to replace anything